# Floating point number based on IEEE 754 how to calculate bias?

Tags: floating-point

A floating point number type is stored based on IEEE 754 standard: Value of the 
number is represented by 9 bits, the first bit is sign bit (1 for negative and 0 for positive). The next 
three bits are used for exponent and the last five is for value.

Convert binary floating points to decimal numbers
100101100

I can't upload my photo, please click link below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTSPK.jpg

Comment: SO is not a homework service!

Comment: It is required, I only ask "how to calculate the bias in Floating point?" Others, I can do myself. Thanks

Comment: I have the solution, but i can't understand "how to calculate the bias"

Comment: Link is broken. Use http://imgur.com please

Comment: I've just edit link http://imgur.com/MC8IASc

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a math question and not about programming. Asking how to solve a math problem with a computer program doesn't make it a programming problem if you're looking for answers that explain how to do the math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow the IEEE-754 pattern, if you have *w* bits for the exponent, the bias is 2<sup>*w*-1</sup>-1, per IEEE 754-2008 3.4, note on page 9:

> *emax* = *bias* = 2<sup>(*w*-1)</sup>-1